# How to edit specific word with delimiter?

Tags: java, file-io

How to manipulate the String **(using delimiter ",")**. In this example, I just wanted to change or update its value (from amount 100 to 90 in item BBB only). I used String Builder to update the file but no luck. :(

```
// Item no, name, description, price, amount
101,AAAA,Cotton with microfiber for sweat,150.00,100
102,BBB,Boosts up speed,100.00,100
103,CCCDFD,Made from fabric,80.00,100
104,SADSDS,Boosts up agility and made from fiber,999.75,100
105,SKJAKLJDLKS,Comes with different colors,500.00,100
```

Comment: And what have you got?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: You have to write a second file, or load everything, and overwrite the original (closed again) file.